# Memory leak on socket

Tags: c++, sockets, memory-management, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I'm writing a tcp proxy and while it seem to work it leaves a memory leak behind. I manipulated the code to forward the incoming packet to itself to create 10000 sockets and close them to see where the leak is. However I can't figure it out. I've used deleaker and it doesn't shows any leak(besides a small one that I don't care.) [image: http://i.imgur.com/7r6u4Jd.png]

But then I untick the two boxes and this comes out.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

***Code:***

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <process.h> /* _beginthread() */

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT    "1234" /* Port to listen on */
#define BUF_SIZE 4096    /* Buffer for  transfers */

typedef struct {

    char *host;
    char *port;
    SOCKET sock;

}
HandleStruct;

unsigned int S2C(SOCKET from, SOCKET to)
{

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    unsigned int disconnected = 0;
    size_t bytes_read, bytes_written;
    bytes_read = recv(from, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    if (bytes_read == 0) {

        disconnected = 1;

    }

    else {

        bytes_written = send(to, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        if (bytes_written == -1) {

            disconnected = 1;

        }


    }

    return disconnected;

}

unsigned int C2S(SOCKET from, SOCKET to)
{

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    unsigned int disconnected = 0;
    size_t bytes_read, bytes_written;
    bytes_read = recv(from, buf, BUF_SIZE, 0);
    if (bytes_read == 0) {

        disconnected = 1;

    }

    else {

        bytes_written = send(to, buf, bytes_read, 0);
        if (bytes_written == -1) {

            disconnected = 1;

        }


    }

    return disconnected;

}

void handle(void *param)
{

    HandleStruct *args = (HandleStruct*) param;
    SOCKET client = args->sock;
    const char *host = args->host;
    const char *port = args->port;
    SOCKET server = -1;
    unsigned int disconnected = 0;
    fd_set set;
    unsigned int max_sock;
    struct addrinfo *res = NULL;
    struct addrinfo *ptr = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    /* Get the address info */
    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    if (getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &res) != 0) {

        perror("getaddrinfo");
        closesocket(client);
        return;

    }

    /* Create the socket */
    server = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (server == INVALID_SOCKET) {

        perror("socket");
        closesocket(client);
        return;

    }

    /* Connect to the host */
    if (connect(server, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1) {

        perror("connect");
        closesocket(client);
        return;

    }

    if (client > server) {

        max_sock = client;

    }

    else {

        max_sock = server;

    }

    /* Main transfer loop */
    while (!disconnected) {

        FD_ZERO(&set);
        FD_SET(client, &set);
        FD_SET(server, &set);
        if (select(max_sock + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

            perror("select");
            break;

        }

        if (FD_ISSET(client, &set)) {

            disconnected = C2S(client, server);

        }

        if (FD_ISSET(server, &set)) {

            disconnected = S2C(server, client);

        }


    }

    closesocket(server);
    closesocket(client);
fprintf(stderr, "Sockets Closed: %d/%d", server, client);
    _endthread();
    return;

}

int _tmain(int argc)
{

    WORD wVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int reuseaddr = 1; /* True */
    /* Initialise Winsock */
    if (iResult = (WSAStartup(wVersion, &wsaData)) != 0) {

        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed: %dn", iResult);
        return 1;

    }

    char * host = "127.0.0.1";
    char * port = "1234";

    /* Get the address info */
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    if (getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &res) != 0) {

        perror("getaddrinfo");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;

    }

    /* Create the socket */
    sock = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

        perror("socket");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;

    }

    /* Enable the socket to reuse the address */
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char*)&reuseaddr,
    sizeof(int)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        perror("setsockopt");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;

    }

    /* Bind to the address */
    if (bind(sock, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        perror("bind");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;

    }

    /* Listen */
    if (listen(sock, 6500) == SOCKET_ERROR) {

        perror("listen");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;

    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);
    int i = 0;

    HandleStruct *arg;
    arg = (HandleStruct *)malloc(sizeof( HandleStruct));
/* Main loop */
    while(1) {

        int size = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
        struct sockaddr_in their_addr;
        SOCKET newsock;
        ZeroMemory(&their_addr, sizeof (struct sockaddr));
        newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&their_addr, &size);

        if (newsock == INVALID_SOCKET) {

            perror("acceptn");

        }
        else {

            arg->sock = newsock;
            arg->host = host;
            arg->port = port;

            if (i < 10000) {
                _beginthread(handle, 0, (void*) arg);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with reading the program in the screenshots you posted; however, you should probably be concerned about this line:

```
arg = (HandleStruct *)malloc(sizeof( HandleStruct));
```

Here you are allocating memory for a `HandleStruct` via [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) which doesn't appear to be cleaned up anywhere with a subsequent call to [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/). You pass `arg` into `handle()` but still don't deallocate the memory.

It doesn't *appear* to be `handle()`'s responsibility to clean `arg` up, so you should probably have a call to `free()` after the `while` loop, or you could allocate the `HandleStruct` at the beginning of each loop and deallocate it at the end.

Or you could save yourself the hassle and use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/), and optionally change your threads to [`std::thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/?kw=thread), which self-documents who owns the memory etc:

```
void handle(std::unique_ptr<HandleStruct> args)
{
    // Manipulate args
    ...
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<HandleStruct> pHandle = std::make_unique<HandleStruct>();
    for (;;)
    {
        ...
        pHandle->sock = newsock;
        pHandle->host = host;
        pHandle->port = port;
        // Create thread:
        std::thread t(&handle, pHandle);
        // Wait for thread to finish so pHandle doesn't change while we are using it on another thread
        // t.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: malloc only causes a single 48bytes memory leak. The program itself uses 1200kb on startup, when I run 10000 threads on it memory usage goes straight up to 5300kb, which is logical if you consider the number of threads created. But shouldn't the memory be freed since the threads are stopped with _endthread?

Comment: Also I can't use your approach, since I can't wait for the thread to finish. I need to create a new concurrent thread on each new socket.

Comment: Done it another way, altho used your answer as a guide!

Comment: @Asmo Glad you managed to fix it! My use of `std::thread::join()` is commented out: I added it in case you needed it, but I assumed you didn't so I left it commented out. By no means you need to use `std::thread::join` when you use `std::thread`

Answer (score 1):

Every socket uses some memory in the operating system.

Here the description in Linux : [accept](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html)

> ```
>    ENOBUFS, ENOMEM
>           Not enough free memory.  This often means that the memory
>           allocation is limited by the socket buffer limits, not by the
>           system memory.
> ```

The OS might not clean them up.

You are also trying to create 10000 threads, these might also take some memory, if the creation doesn't fail long before with `errno` set to `EAGAIN`.